# multisite creation and content sharing per role bases - Drupal Multisite

Tags: multi-sites, subsites

I am building on one Drupal project where we have 1 main site and n number of sub-sites. The requirements are as follows per role base:

**Super Admin**

1. Can create a n number of sub sites from main site front-end (a.foo.com, b.foo.com). We have wildcard entry for foo.com
2. Can administer any sub-site created from main site.
3. Can create content and can choose under which sub-site it will be available.
4. Can create menus and can choose under which sub-site it will be available.
5. Can create users (admin/editor/approver) for sub-sites.
6. Should be able to set permission for the users (admin/editor/approver). For example add/remove/edit global navigation within the boundaries that the OEM Super Admin set for the site theme

**Sub-Site Admin**

1. Modify content and blocks only for his sub site.
2. Modify theme, create new theme.
3. Configure google analytics and other social media plugins.

**Issue**

1. Which module to choose Domain Access, Sites, Spaces, Organic Group?
2. Solution for both Drupal 6 & Drupal 7